# Перемещение объекта по рандомной траектории

Tags: javascript, jquery

Есть такой код-игра футбол на JQuery-по клику на мяч он должен перемещаться из левой половины поля в правую и наоборот. Но у меня получается, что мяч только один-два раза в начале игры перемещается между половинами поля, потом только на левой. Как переделать условие, чтобы после каждого клика движение было слева направо и обратно?

```js
var height = $('.field').height();
var width = $('.field').width();
var ballWidth = $('.ball').width();


function getRandom(min, max) {
    var index = parseInt(Math.random() * (max - min + 1)) + min;
    console.log(index);

    return index;
}

// считаем голы
function goal() {
    var xBall = $('.ball').offset().left;
    var yBall = $('.ball').offset().top;
    if ((xBall >= 400) && (yBall <= 600)) {
        $('.goal-wrapper').toggleClass('active').toggle("scale");
        goalCountRight++;
        $('.football__scoreboard .right').text(goalCountRight);
    }
    if ((xBall <= 400) && (yBall >= 600)) {
        $('.goal-wrapper').toggleClass('active').toggle("scale");
        goalCountLeft++;
        $('.football__scoreboard .left').text(goalCountLeft);
    }
}


var flag = 0;
var goalCountRight = 0;
var goalCountLeft = 0;

$('.ball').on('click', function () {
    if (flag == 0) {
        var a = getRandom(20, height - ballWidth);
        $(this).animate({
            left: (width - ballWidth),
            top: a
        }), 2000, goal();

        flag = 1;
    } else {
        var a = getRandom(13, height - ballWidth);
        $(this).animate({
            left: a,
            top: 0
        }), 2000, goal();

    }
});
```

```css
.football {
    position: relative;
    margin-top: 20px;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
}

.field {
    width: 100%;
    border-radius: 10px;
}

.ball {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
}

.football__scoreboard {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    width: 100%;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-size: 30px;

}

.football__scoreboard p {
    margin: 0;
}

.goal-wrapper {
    position: fixed;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    opacity: 0;
    visibility: hidden;
    overflow-y: auto;
    overflow-x: hidden;
    /* transition: 2s ; */
    z-index: 5000;
}

.goal {

    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-size: 50px;
    font-weight: bold;
    color: #fff;
}

.active {

    opacity: 1;
    visibility: visible;

}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="ru">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>Футбол-понг</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css" />
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="football">
      <div class="football__scoreboard">
        <span class="left">0</span>
        <p>-</p>
        <span class="right">0</span>
      </div>
      <img class="field" alt="Поле" src="img/field.jpg" />
      <img class="ball" alt="Мяч" src="img/ball.png" />
      <div class="goal-wrapper">
        <p class="goal">ГООООЛ!!!</p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <script src="js/jquery-3.5.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.0/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/script.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: "Чего в этом супе не хватает?" - HTML-а и стилей.

Comment: @igor, я всё добавил. Поле-картинка поля, мяч-тоже.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вам нужно делать рандом не относительно всего поля, а относительно части поля на которую должен попасть мяч.

Пример:
Поле - 200px, соответсвенно каждая сторона шириной по 100px. Когда мяч на левой стороне, нам нужно брать рандом относительно правой, т.е. `getRandom(100, 200)`, когда на левой - наоборот `getRandom(0, 100)`.

И да, Igor привёл дельное замечание по поводу раставления скобок

```js
var height = $(".field").height();
var width = $(".field").width();
var ballWidth = $(".ball").width();

function getRandom(min, max) {
  var index = parseInt(Math.random() * (max - min + 1)) + min;
  console.log(index);

  return index;
}

// считаем голы
function goal() {
  var xBall = $(".ball").offset().left;
  var yBall = $(".ball").offset().top;
  if (xBall >= 400 && yBall <= 600) {
    $(".goal-wrapper").toggleClass("active").toggle("scale");
    goalCountRight++;
    $(".football__scoreboard .right").text(goalCountRight);
  }
  if (xBall <= 400 && yBall >= 600) {
    $(".goal-wrapper").toggleClass("active").toggle("scale");
    goalCountLeft++;
    $(".football__scoreboard .left").text(goalCountLeft);
  }
}

var flag = 0;
var goalCountRight = 0;
var goalCountLeft = 0;
var side = 0;

$(".ball").on("click", function () {
  side = (side + 1) % 2;
  if (flag == 0) {
    var a = getRandom(20, height - ballWidth);
    $(this).animate(
      {
        left: width - ballWidth,
        top: a
      },
      2000,
      goal()
    );

    flag = 1;
  } else {
    var a =
      side == 0
        ? getRandom(13, width / 2 - ballWidth)
        : getRandom(width / 2, width - ballWidth);
    $(this).animate(
      {
        left: a,
        top: getRandom(0, height - ballWidth)
      },
      2000,
      goal()
    );
  }
});
```

```css
.football {
  position: relative;
  margin-top: 20px;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}

.field {
  width: 100%;
  border-radius: 10px;
}

.ball {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
}

.football__scoreboard {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  width: 100%;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  font-size: 30px;
}

.football__scoreboard p {
  margin: 0;
}

.goal-wrapper {
  position: fixed;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  opacity: 0;
  visibility: hidden;
  overflow-y: auto;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  /* transition: 2s ; */
  z-index: 5000;
}

.goal {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  font-size: 50px;
  font-weight: bold;
  color: #fff;
}

.active {
  opacity: 1;
  visibility: visible;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="ru">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8" />
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
  <title>Футбол-понг</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css" />
</head>

<body>
  <div class="football">
    <div class="football__scoreboard">
      <span class="left">0</span>
      <p>-</p>
      <span class="right">0</span>
    </div>
    <img class="field" alt="Поле" src="https://via.placeholder.com/500" />
    <img class="ball" alt="Мяч" src="https://via.placeholder.com/100/FF0000" />
    <div class="goal-wrapper">
      <p class="goal">ГООООЛ!!!</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <script src="js/jquery-3.5.1.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.0/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
  <script src="js/script.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: отлично, работает, благодарствую! А как вот все это пересчитать в процентах, чтобы работало на устройствах с разными разрешениями экрана и считать голы, если будет величины в процентах?

Comment: @Summersby, `height()` и `width()` возвращают текущий размер так что если вы на css уменьшите картинку, то вам вернётся соответсвующий размер. Если размер экрана изменился, то берёте новую ширину и высоту. Так же, внезапно, `100% / 2 = 50%`. Т.е. можно считать в процентах

Comment: ,считать - то я, внезапно, умею, вот с кодом пока сложности

Answer (score 1):

Что-то здесь не так:

```
    $(this).animate({
      ...
    }), 2000, goal();
```

---

```
    $(this).animate({
      ...
    }, 2000, goal());
     ^             ^
```

```js
var height = $('.field').height();
var width = $('.field').width();
var ballWidth = $('.ball').width();


function getRandom(min, max) {
    var index = parseInt(Math.random() * (max - min + 1)) + min;
    console.log(index);

    return index;
}

// считаем голы
function goal() {
    var xBall = $('.ball').offset().left;
    var yBall = $('.ball').offset().top;
    if ((xBall >= 400) && (yBall <= 600)) {
        $('.goal-wrapper').toggleClass('active').toggle("scale");
        goalCountRight++;
        $('.football__scoreboard .right').text(goalCountRight);
    }
    if ((xBall <= 400) && (yBall >= 600)) {
        $('.goal-wrapper').toggleClass('active').toggle("scale");
        goalCountLeft++;
        $('.football__scoreboard .left').text(goalCountLeft);
    }
}


var flag = 0;
var goalCountRight = 0;
var goalCountLeft = 0;

$('.ball').on('click', function () {
console.log('.ball click');
    if (flag == 0) {
        var a = getRandom(20, height - ballWidth);
        $(this).animate({
            left: (width - ballWidth),
            top: a
        }, 2000, goal());

        flag = 1;
    } else {
        var a = getRandom(13, height - ballWidth);
        $(this).animate({
            left: a,
            top: 0
        }, 2000, goal());

    }
});
```

```css
.football {
    position: relative;
    margin-top: 20px;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
}

.field {
  border:1px solid green;
    width: 100%;
    border-radius: 10px;
}

.ball {
  border:1px solid red;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
}

.football__scoreboard {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    width: 100%;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-size: 30px;

}

.football__scoreboard p {
    margin: 0;
}

.goal-wrapper {
    position: fixed;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    opacity: 0;
    visibility: hidden;
    overflow-y: auto;
    overflow-x: hidden;
    /* transition: 2s ; */
    z-index: 5000;
}

.goal {

    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-size: 50px;
    font-weight: bold;
    color: #fff;
}

.active {

    opacity: 1;
    visibility: visible;

}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="ru">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>Футбол-понг</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css" />
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="football">
      <div class="football__scoreboard">
        <span class="left">0</span>
        <p>-</p>
        <span class="right">0</span>
      </div>
      <img class="field" alt="Поле" src="img/field.jpg" />
      <img class="ball" alt="Мяч" src="img/ball.png" />
      <div class="goal-wrapper">
        <p class="goal">ГООООЛ!!!</p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <script src="js/jquery-3.5.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.0/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/script.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```